# Pandas: Replace a set of rows by their sum

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure there is a neat way of doing this, but haven't had any luck finding it yet.

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'C':[100, 200, 300, 400]}).T
```

that is, with rows indexed A, B and C.

Now suppose I want to take rows A and B, and replace them both by a single row that is their sum; and, moreover, that I want to assign a given index (say 'sum') to that replacement row (note the order of indices doesn't matter).

At the moment I'm having to do:

```
f.append(pd.DataFrame(f.ix[['A','B']].sum()).T).drop(['A','B'])
```

followed by something equally clunky to set the index of the replacement row. However, I'm curious to know if there's an elegant, one-line way of doing both of these steps?

Comment: this simple idea is grotesque to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
In [79]: f.append(f.loc[['A', 'B']].sum(), ignore_index=True).drop([0, 1]).set_index(Index(['C', 'sumAB'])
)
Out[79]:
         0    1    2    3
C      100  200  300  400
sumAB   11   22   33   44
```

Alternatively you can use `Index.get_indexer` for an even uglier one-liner:

```
In [96]: f.append(f.loc[['A', 'B']].sum(), ignore_index=True).drop(f.index.get_indexer(['A', 'B'])).set_index(Index(['C', 'sumAB']))
Out[96]:
         0    1    2    3
C      100  200  300  400
sumAB   11   22   33   44
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html):

```
In [11]: AB = list('AB')
```

First select the rows you wish to sum:

```
In [12]: f.loc[AB]
Out[12]: 
    0   1   2   3
A   1   2   3   4
B  10  20  30  40

In [13]: f.loc[AB].sum()
Out[13]: 
0    11
1    22
2    33
3    44
dtype: int64
```

and as a row in a DataFrame *(Note: this step may not be necessary in future versions...)*:

```
In [14]: pd.DataFrame({'sumAB': f.loc[AB].sum()}).T
Out[14]: 
        0   1   2   3
sumAB  11  22  33  44
```

and we want to concat with all the remaining rows:

```
In [15]: f.loc[f.index - AB]
Out[15]: 
     0    1    2    3
C  100  200  300  400

In [16]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'sumAB': f.loc[AB].sum()}).T,
                        f.loc[f.index - AB]],
                   axis=0)
Out[16]: 
         0    1    2    3
sumAB   11   22   33   44
C      100  200  300  400
```